# Authentication using ldap in spring

Tags: spring, ldap

Currently I work with datasource and spring in order to be autheticate,

this is my config in **security-app-context.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/administration/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/citizen/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
        <form-login login-page="/index.htm" authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessRedirecthandler"
          default-target-url = "/citizen/test.htm"
            authentication-failure-url="/index.htm?error=1"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.htm" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean class="com.test.redirect.CustomAuthenticationHandler" id="authenticationSuccessRedirecthandler"></beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-username-query="select username, password, enabled from users where username=?" authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

and this is CustomAuthenticationHandler.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

public class CustomAuthenticationHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

 @Override
 public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

     String targetUrl = "/test/page.htm";

      Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());


      if (roles.contains("ADMIN")) {

         getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
      }  else {
         super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
         return;
      }
   }
}
```

I want to know to correct config in order to authenticate not with datasource but with ldap

this is same parameter in my ldap :

```
Base Provider URL
ldap://192.168.0.88:389

Base DN

DC=MINISTER,DC=FR

Principal

CN=LDAP Requester,OU=Users,OU=Technical Accounts,OU=P9 Accounts,DC=MINISTER,DC=FR

Credentials

minister$9999

Users

Authentication Search Filter

(&(objectClass=person)(mail=@email_address@))

Users DN DC=MINISTER,DC=FR

Groups DN DC=MINISTER,DC=FR
```

**updated :**

I try with this code :

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/administration/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/citizen/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/menu/menu.htm"  access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','USER')" />   


         <form-login login-page="/index.htm"
          default-target-url = "/citizen/test.htm"
            authentication-failure-url="/index.htm?error=1"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.htm" />


    </http>



         <beans:bean id="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" class="com.test.ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper"/>

    <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" />

    </authentication-manager> 
    <beans:bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="DC=MINISTER,DC=TN" />
        <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://192.168.0.88:389" />
        <beans:property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" />
        <beans:property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

and this is a java class :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.GrantedAuthoritiesMapper;

/**
 * Maps the groups defined in LDAP nomenclature to roles for a specific user.
 */
public class ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper implements GrantedAuthoritiesMapper {

    // Constants for group defined in LDAP
    private static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "ADMIN";


    public ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper() {
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(
            final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

        Set<SecurityContextAuthority> roles = EnumSet.noneOf(SecurityContextAuthority.class);

        for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
            // authority.getAuthority() returns the role in LDAP nomenclature
            if (ROLE_ADMIN.equals(authority.getAuthority())) {
                roles.add(SecurityContextAuthority.ROLE_ADMIN);

            }
        }
        return roles;
    }

}
```

and this is SecurityContextAuthority.java class

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

/**
 * Maps the groups defined in LDAP to roles for a specific user.
 */
public enum SecurityContextAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {

    // These roles are specified in the security context (security.xml) and are
    // mapped to LDAP roles by the ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper
    ROLE_ADMIN;

    public String getAuthority() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

but when I test I have this error :

```
[org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this same thing, and my code is working.  Looking over your code, I only spot one difference with my code.  In your security config file, in the `ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider` bean, your two constructor args are:

```
<beans:constructor-arg value="DC=MINISTER,DC=TN" />
<beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://192.168.0.88:389" />
```

Mine follow a different construct; using your values, it would be like this:

```
<beans:constructor-arg value="192.168.0.88" />
<beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://192.168.0.88" />
```

You may need to pass the domain components too, but I'm wondering if your config needs to have both the domain and the URL passed in.  Also, I've noticed that it seems to add the default port, so I leave it off my URL.